# Android RecyclerView - parent views steal touch events for children of grid items that have negative out-of-bounds placement

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view

We have a grid layout that looks like the picture below. I've enabled the dev option to show layout bounds to help explain the problem I'm having.

This is a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`. This is pseudo-XML of the grid item layout:

```xml
<!-- list_item.xml -->
<FrameLayout clipChildren="false">
  <Tile margin="16dp" />
  <DeleteButton marginTop="-8dp" marginStart="-8dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The delete button is the circular 'X' button that appears at the top left of each tile in the image below. It has a negative margin so that it goes slightly out of bounds of the grid item itself.

---

The parent `RecyclerView` and other relevant views in the hierarchy have `clipChildren="false"` set so that the remove action is not cut off by any parent views:

```xml
<!-- main_page.xml -->
<LinearLayout clipChildren="false">
    <Tabs clipChildren="false"> ... </Tabs>
    <RecyclerView clipChildren="false" layoutManager="grid" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And it looks like this:

[image: layout visual]

So, the problem I'm having here is: **the parts of the delete buttons that are not in bounds of their tiles is not touchable.** In the image above, the part of the delete. buttons that are covered in dark pink are not touchable. *It seems as though the parent `RecyclerView` (or whatever is underneath the touched point) steals the touch event, based on my debugging.*

Is there an attribute or something I could use in the view hierarchy to get the touch events to hit the right view? **It's especially noticeable in the top/left 2 delete buttons, where the touch events go through to the tabs underneath, which are at the top (containing blurred titles).** It's as if the view system ignores the negative margined views.

---

Update, Android Studio's layout inspector shows a bit more:

[image: layout visual 2]

Even though the views are visible in practice, they are covered as far as the View system is concerned.